# python : replace mutiple words in a file

Tags: python

I have a file `apple.py`,it has words `apple` and `Apple`.
And there is a blank file `pear.py`.

I want to read the content of `apple.py` and write it into `pear.py`,and modify
`apple` to `pear`,
`Apple` to `Pear`.

I do it like this:

```
def modify_city():
    with open('city.py', 'r+') as f:
        read_data = f.read()
    with open('beijing', 'w') as f:
        f.write(read_data.replace('city', 'beijing'))  #it works
        f.write(read_data.replace('City', 'Beijing'))  #it doesn't work
```

**Question:**
In the code,the first `replace()` works, but the second `replace()` doesn't work.what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You're writing the whole of read_data to the file twice.

```
read_data = read_data.replace('city','beijing')
read_data = read_data.replace('City','Beijing')
f.write(read_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reasons why your code does not work is:

1. You write whole data to file twice.
2. `str.replace()` **returns** string with replace done, not changes the original string. By doing

   ```
   f.write(read_data.replace('city', 'beijing'))
   ```

   first time, you print to file `read_data` with replaced `'city'` and `'beijing'` but you do **not** save changes to `read_data`. The second time when you do

   ```
   f.write(read_data.replace('City', 'Beijing'))
   ```

   the previous replace isn't saved, thus resulting in replacing the original string.

This being said, you have two options:

```
def modify_city():
    with open('city.py', 'r+') as f:
        read_data = f.read()
    with open('beijing.py', 'w') as f:
        f.write(read_data.replace('city', 'beijing').replace('City', 'Beijing'))
```

or

```
def modify_city():
    with open('city.py', 'r+') as f:
        read_data = f.read()
    read_data = read_data.replace('city', 'beijing')
    read_data = read_data.replace('City', 'Beijing')
    with open('beijing.py', 'w') as f:
        f.write(read_data)
```